# CMD+Shift+A alternative in iTerm

Tags: terminal, iterm2, iterm, macos-sierra

In Terminal app in macOS Sierra user can select the output with CMD+Shift+A.
E.g. do a ls command, then do CMD+Shift+A shortcut. The output of the ls command will be selected.

How to do the same in iTerm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same shortcut. You just need to install its shell integration.

[image: menu]